# PHP turning 2 lines into 1 line

Tags: php

```
My son seems very interested.
 Do you know why my game started?
```

Above is a string line, I tried to form it as

```
My son seems very interested. Do you know why my game started?
```

I tried the following code

```
$finish_loop = "no";

while($finish_loop=="no")
{

if(!strstr($dialogue,"  "))
{$finish_loop = "yes";}

$dialogue = str_replace("  "," ",$dialogue);
}
```

But the $dialogue still return the $dialogue as 2 lines, I just want everything in 1 line, how do I achieve this with php

Comment: note: use a bool. using strings (`"yes"` / `"no"`) is bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the new lines from your text with space, then trim it to remove the superflus spaces :

```
$dialogue = str_replace("\n\r"," ",$dialogue);
$dialogue = str_replace("\r"," ",$dialogue);
$dialogue = trim(str_replace("\n"," ",$dialogue));
```